# How octopus develops its imitation skill?

Tags: evolution, zoology, behaviour

I've watched one documentary about a [Mimic octopus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimic_octopus) which they can imitate another animals in several form e.g. a Lion fish, a Sea snake, a Flatfish, etc. My question is how these octopuses can have these such skills? Imagine that they can not see themselves via a mirror but their imitation is so perfect.

What is a theory behind this?

Comment: well other animals do imitation and sometimes cant see themselves, the wikipedia describes two types of mimicry that it exhibits: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batesian_mimicry  and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggressive_mimicry

Comment: There are even theories that some [squid and octopuses have monochromatic vision](http://www.sciencefriday.com/blogs/01/26/2011/are-cephalopods-really-colorblind.html), yet have the ability to change colour. Go figure!

Comment: I am confused about the use of the tag `evolution` in your question. Are you interested in the physiology of mimicry in octopuses or about the evolution of the mimicry?